# Apache tomcat 9 SSL connector: have to manually write https:// the first attempt on a browser

Tags: apache-http-server, https, ssl-certificate, tomcat, oracle-linux

thanks in advance for any help.

I've set up an apache tomcat 9 environment to access my site with an SSL certificate. The issue is that I need it to be able to access to the site by just typing in the browser mysite.com, yet is not working until I manually type "https:// mysite. com" , but after I type https:// the first time, only then I can access mysite.com and automatically goes to "https:// mysite. com" .

I need it to be accesible for users from the first attempt without manually typing https://

For the server(oracle linux 7) firewall I'm forwarding and allowing access to some ports as shown bellow:

```
#  firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens3
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 22/tcp 8080/tcp 443/tcp 5901/tcp 80/tcp 55555/tcp 9090/tcp 8443/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: port=443:proto=tcp:toport=8443:toaddr=
    port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8443:toaddr=
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

And for the apache connector in "conf/server.xml" I've configured it as following:

```
 <Connector port="8443"
            maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
            maxThreads="150"
            minSpareThreads="25"
            maxSpareThreads="75"
            enableLookups="false"
            disableUploadTimeout="true"
            acceptCount="100"
            scheme="https"
            secure="true"
            SSLEnabled="true"
            clientAuth="false"
            sslProtocol="TLS"
            keyAlias="vennii"
            keystoreFile="keystorefile.jks"
            keystorePass="keystorepassword" />
```

I really appretiate any help I can get!
Thanks again!

Comment: Your firewall is mapping port 80 (on which browser expects HTTP) to 8443 (which only provides HTTPS and thus won't work). Make it 80->8080, and have an HTTP connector on 8080 in Tomcat (you say on the answer you do).

Answer (score 0):

[According to the Internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=tomcat+https+redirect), at the very least, you seem to need an HTTP connector in `conf/server.xml` with a `redirectPort` statement:

```
<!-- HTTP Connector -->
<Connector port="8080"
           ...
           redirectPort="8443"
           ... >
```

[Note that some suggestions](https://medium.com/@anil7017/redirect-http-request-to-https-in-apache-tomcat-bcd710daabf4) also include `protocol="HTTP/1.1"` after the `port` statement.

You also likely need to have the following in `conf/web.xml` ([apparantly after any servelet-mapping tags](https://www.journaldev.com/160/steps-to-configure-ssl-on-tomcat-and-setup-auto-redirect-from-http-to-https)) to redirect the entire application:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

**Notes**

- Be aware that `...` are not intended to be literal (above). They indicate placeholders for any other relevant statements.
- Don't forget to restart Tomcat to apply your changes.
- If you do not wish to specify the port in the URL (i.e. use just e.g. `http://example.com` or `https://example.com`), you should use port `80` and `443` instead of `8080` and `8443`.
- Remember that `http://example.com`, `https://example.com`, `http://www.example.com` and `https://www.example.com` can all be considered separate addresses and should be handled as such.

Comment: Hi anaksunaman, thanks for the help! 
As mentioned on your response, there's already an 8080 connector redirecting to 8443, so I added de `conf/web.xml` as explained, then restarted tomcat but still getting the same issue.

Regarding the notes, I'd like it to be as the third point, but as I researched, linux has restrictions for ports under 1024, therefore the port-forwarding I mentioned earlier.